# Print Using Barcode Font

Tags: c#, text, ms-office, barcode

I need to throw up some barcodes in the shop for employees to use to scan the appropriate responses.

I've got a C# app that can create fonts for our labels, but here I just want to select my **Code 128** font in Microsoft Word and print it out.

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) shows I need a start/stop character and a check character in addition to my regular text. This means that selecting the text `SCAN_YES` and changing the font from **Times New Roman** to **Code 128** will not cut it. I tried it, but the barcode reader can't read it.

[image: barcode128]

I'm trying to follow along in the wiki doc, but I just don't get it.

For **Weight 1**, wiki shows **Start Code A** having value 103, but my ASCII chart says 103 is the letter `g`.

Then, wiki shows a **Sum**, **Divisor**, **Sum/Divisor**, and **Remainder & Check Sum Value**. Now I'm really lost. What are these for?

Is there a place that has **Code128 For Dummies** or could someone explain it to this Dummy?

Comment: Can you use another font?  Code 39 is a little easier, and more MS Word friendly, because you just have to put a leading and trailing asterisk.

Comment: QC had us change to Code128 because of all the bad scans we were getting with Code 39. I found an example [here](http://www.jtbarton.com/Barcodes/Code128.aspx), but I still don't know how to take the totals and use those to create the barcode!

Comment: http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-faq/code-128/ has good examples.  It's easy to confuse ASCII value with barcode value!

Comment: One possible solution is to use barcode font for displaying or generating barcodes in C# application, and then print them in C#. Check this [C# barcode file](http://www.keepautomation.com/font_tools/csharp_barcode_library_font_encoder.html), which is able to print barcodes in C# using barcode font.

Comment: Hi Ward. The barcode font was easy to download and install, but those fonts rely on me to add the **Weight 1**, **Sum**, **Divisor**, **Sum/Divisor**, and **Remainder & Check Sum Value**. They will create a barcode out of the text you enter, but a Code 128 barcode font that only has "Hello World" will not scan because it is missing all of the other validation parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to stick to human readable characters you should use Code 128 'B'.

This is what I get in Code 'B':
[image]

Comment: That looks good, Brian. Did you create a little Excel spreadsheet for that?

Comment: Yes, you can download it from notionovus.com

Comment: There is a "Start Here' tab where you can find the calculations and an 'HTML' tab where it generates the barcode for a web page (no font needed).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm going to start with `SCAN_YES` and show what I'd do to convert it. You guys pitch in and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I'm going with Start Set A. (Good/Bad?)

```
                    Weighted
Character    Value    Value    Total
Start Set A   103   103         103
S             83    83*1         83
C             67    67*2        134
A             65    65*3        195
N             78    78*4        312
_             95    95*5        475
Y             89    89*6        534
E             69    69*7        483
S             83    83*8        664
                    Total      2983
```

Modulus is 99 because `2983 / 103 = 28 R 99`.

So, my encoded Code128 A barcode should be:

```
103(Code A=g)+83(S)+67(C)+65(A)+78(N)+95(_)+89(Y)+69(E)+83(S)+99(c)+106(stop=j)
```

Would, then, I change my Text in my MS Word document to be `gSCAN_YEScj`, then select my Code128 Barcode Font?

Apparently, that is not right, because that text put into barcode font will not scan with my barcode reader.

What if the modulus is an unprintable number like 7 (Audible bell)?

[image: ASCII Chart]

Comment: Use the table in the link that [you shared](http://www.jtbarton.com/Barcodes/Code128.aspx).  `Start Set A == ASCII 0203`

Comment: If you click deeper, they have assemblies you can download.

Comment: Using their chart, would my modulus 99 be input as a **g** or **Ç** (ASCII 0199)?

Comment: Bleh! That (Ç) doesn't scan either. FWIW: I've got a C# program that prints barcodes, but I was just looking for a way to print out a sheet of barcodes that I could format to fit the page easily.